# how add fragment from function?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to create fragment with background on Screen for load query.

It is not working, I cannot see fragment on screen

```
public class internet {
    startQueryAsync(final Activity activity) {

       new Thread() {

            RelativeLayout backView = new RelativeLayout(activity);

            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        FragmentLoad fr = new FragmentLoad();
                        activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fr);
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
   }
}


public class FragmentLoad extends Fragment {

    public FragmentLoad() {
        super();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load, container);
       view.setLayoutParams(lpFr);

       return view;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: you failed to  commit the fragment (i.e) activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fr).commit();

Comment: I'm added commit, but I'm anyway not see this frame on screen

Comment: Try running fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() after committing your transaction...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't committed you fragment transaction. Change your method like this

```
public void run() {
    FragmentLoad fr = new FragmentLoad();
    activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fr).commit(); // change this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do the `commit();` of the `fragment`.

For example:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // First, create your FragmentManager.
        FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();

        // Then, create your transaction.
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        // Add your fragment in the view.
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentLoad());

        // Commit the transaction.
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

You can use the [Fluent Interface Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) to do too:

```
activity.getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentLoad())
    .commit();
```

For more details, see the [Google Fragment Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Hope this helps.